# What is the right way to interface polymorphism with DbContext?

Tags: .net, interface, asp.net-core, polymorphism, dbcontext

Is there a way to **get an instance of dbcontext directly in the repository** instead of getting an instance of dbcontext in the controller?

**I wish to pass it all the way to the method in the repository** ?

**step 1 - controller**

```
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    public class ModulesApiController : Controller
    {
        private readonly ApplicationDbContext _dbContext;

        private readonly ILogger _logger;
      

        public ModulesApiController(ILoggerFactory loggerFactory, **ApplicationDbContext dbContext**)
        {
            _logger = loggerFactory.CreateLogger<ModulesApiController>();
            _dbContext = dbContext;
        }


        [HttpGet]
        [Route("GetModule/{module}")]
        public async Task<JsonResult> GetModule(string module)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                try
                {
                    var ListModules = new List<ImoduleBL>();
                    ImoduleBL obj = new HomeModuleBL();
                    if (module == "home-index")
                    {
                        //obj = new HomeModuleBL();
                        //ListModules.Add(obj as ImoduleBL);
                        //List<Layout> ListObj = await GetModuleService.GetModule(ListModules);
                        //return Json(ListObj);
                    }
                    else if (module == "shop-index")
                    {
                        obj = new ShopModuleBL();
                        ImoduleBL Iobj = obj as ImoduleBL;
                        return  await GetModuleService.GetCateroy(Iobj, _dbContext);

                    }
                    else if (module == "top-bunner")
                    {

                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    _logger.LogError("Failed of : GetLayOutFor - Index Module", ex);
                    return null;
                }
            }
            return null;
        }
}
```

**step 2 - GetModuleService - Service**

public class GetModuleService
{
// _dbContext - pass it all the way to the method in the repository

```
public static async Task<JsonResult> GetCateroy(ImoduleBL ListModules, ApplicationDbContext _dbContext)
{
        return await ListModules.GetCateroy(_dbContext);
}
```

}

**step 3 - ShopModuleBL - BL**

```
    public class ShopModuleBL : ImoduleBL
    {

        public async Task<JsonResult> GetCateroy(ApplicationDbContext _dbContext)
        {
            ImoduleBL ListModules;
            ShopModuleRepo obj = new ShopModuleRepo();
            ListModules = obj as ImoduleBL;
            return await GetModuleService.GetCateroy(ListModules, _dbContext);
        }

}
```

**step 4 - ShopModuleRepo - repository **

```
public class ShopModuleRepo : ImoduleBL
{

    public async Task<JsonResult> GetCateroy(ApplicationDbContext _dbContext)
    {
        return new JsonResult(await _dbContext.Category1s.ToListAsync());
    }
```

}

**step 5 - client side - cs **
the Result pass to angular app.....

**Thank you**

Answer (score 0):

You should use constructor injection, not method injection. As you can see you are passing the db-context-instance through every method, all the way to the repository. If you use constructor injection, you don't have to do this.

Unfortunately you are newing up instances all over the place. If you want to use constructor injection, it will probably be benificial to change your design to use Inversion Of Control. Lots of articles about this, look into it.

Your repository will look like this.

```
public class ShopModuleRepo : ImoduleBL
{
    public ShopModuleRepo(ApplicationDbContext dbContext) {
         if (dbContext == null)
             throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(dbContext));

        _dbContext = dbContext;
    }

    private readonly ApplicationDbContext _dbContext;

    public async Task<JsonResult> GetCateroy()
    {
        return new JsonResult(await _dbContext.Category1s.ToListAsync());
    }
}
```

Note the absence of parameters in method `GetCateroy`.

Now you can remove the db-context field from the controller, and remove all db-context parameters in all the other classes.

Comment: Thank intention to IoC certainly very effective, but with solution suggested I stay with the same problem.

I am calling to ShopModuleRepo - frome ShopModuleBL like this:  ShopModuleRepo obj = new ShopModuleRepo();  ,   Note that there is no parameter in constractor , and that's why i stay with the same problem